# Uncaught ReferenceError: doit is not defined

Tags: javascript, function

I'm writing a small userscript to include a link next to user's profile image for a phpBB forum that I frequent. On clicking the link, I'm getting an error like below:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: doit is not defined
(anonymous function)            viewtopic.php:542
onclick                         viewtopic.php:543
```

Portion of the userscript:

```
(function(){

    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.textContent = '(' + twk.toString() + ')();';
    document.body.appendChild(script);

    function twk() {

        pd = document.getElementsByClassName('postdetails');

        for (i=0 ; i<(pd.length); i++) {
            ele = document.createElement("a");
            ele.innerHTML ='<a href=\'#\' onclick=\'doit();\'>Quick reply</a>';

            pd[i].appendChild(ele);

        }

   function  doit() {
        selec = document.getSelection().anchorNode.textContent;
        document.getElementsByClassName("row2").item('message').innerHTML = selec;

    }

}




})();
```

Can anyone please point out where/what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, you're creating your element all wrong. It should be like this:

```
var link = document.createElement('a');
link.setAttribute('href', '#');
link.innerHTML = 'New text';
```

And to add an event to it:

`link.onclick = doit`

Finally, add it to the page like you're doing:

`pd[i].appendChild(ele);`

You might want to consider using a framework like jQuery or Mootools, it will make your life much easier.  Sometimes there are conflicts with browsers doing stuff like that.  I personally like Mootools, but jQuery is easier to pick up, especially for small projects.

EDIT:

I added the innerHTML to the example.  I would just use a framework instead of doing this the hard way though.

Comment: No second of all? ;) How do I add the text to the anchor?

Comment: @Sathya, `var text = document.createTextNode("text goes here"); link.appendChild(text);`

Answer (score 3):

unwrap everything from that outer anon function and it should work:

Comment: Bingo. The `onclick` attribute can't access the the `doit` function because it's encapsulated inside the self-invoking anonymous function. That function is meant to hide any global variables, so trying to access anything from outside of the function will lead to errors.

Comment: Dilemma. Did changes as suggested by you as well as that mentioned @Tjameson and both helped. Can't figure which answer to accept :\ Thanks.